# Serving static files in Express (express.static vs app.static)

Tags: node.js, express

Through serving static files in Express .. I saw below code:

```
const express    = require('express');
const app        = express();

// Initialize the main project folder
app.use(express.static('website'));
```

Why we didn't use `app.static()` instead of `express.static()` as we already assigned `express()` to the `app` constant, and what is the difference between them?

Note: I tried to replace `express` with `app` and it said `app.static is not a function`. I also saw some NPM packages that use `app.static()` like `wamjs` for example, which is weird.

Comment: `express` and `express()` are two different things. Plus, it's the way it's [documented](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). Whatever `wamjs` is doing is separate from express. In the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wamjs) `app` is assigned as `new Wam()`, so not express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.static()` has nothing to do with Express.

`Wam` is a completely different framework (that may be Express-like in some ways, but it's not Express and not identical to Express).  Here's a description on the [NPM wam.js page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wamjs):

***Wam is a small koa and next.js inspired middleware framework for node***.

If you want to program with Express, then use the Express documentation, not the Wam documentation and it will guide you to use `app.use(somePath, express.static())`.  You can see in the [Express doc for the `app` object](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app), there is no mention of `app.static()`.  That is apparently something that wasm.js invented for it's own framework.

> Why we didn't use app.static() instead of express.static() as we already assigned express() to the app constant, and what is the difference between them?

Because Express doesn't have `app.static()`.  It has `express.static()`.

> I also saw some NPM packages that use app.static() like wamjs for example, which is weird.

I wouldn't call it weird.  wamjs is a different package with a different API.  It is not Express so there should be no expectation that Express behaves like wamjs or that wamjs behaves like Express.  They are different frameworks.